# C# WPF Datagrid slow Scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, scroll, datagrid

I have a problem with scrolling my datagrid. I am using a WPF C# application with the 4.7.2 .NET Framework. I load about 5000 datasets into a datatable, which I display with a datagrid. When I run the program through the Visual Studio 2019 compiler and scroll through the records, the result is actually good. However, if I start the program via the .exe, the whole thing hangs a bit when scrolling. I've found a few things on the forum and tried them, but it didn't work out well for me =>

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=False />
```

When I try this, the scrolling result is better, but the performance when loading the database is extremely poor.

```
<DataGrid Width = 400, Height = 400/>

<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

One post mentioned that the height of the data grid and the cells should be adjusted. However, that was also unsuccessful

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"

ItemsSource="{Binding MyStuff, IsAsync=True}" />
```

I've had the best results so far with VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard". Scrolling is still quite choppy, but it doesn't load for as long. Optionally, you can set the item source IsAsync=True, but that didn't really help much anymore.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a better way to avoid loss of performance and to be able to scroll smoothly. Do you have any other ideas? Kind regards

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: to diagnose the issue you can use a profiler, in Visual Studio go to Debug\Performance Profiler...

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I tried the profiler and it showed me that scrolling the program doubled the UI performance. (UI: 80%) On the other hand, if I just open the program and load the data, it's just 40.6%!

Comment: There are many things that can break virtualization in datagrids and affect performance. We need to see the control containing the datagrid and the templates being used by the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar issue. Try it with `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"  RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="10" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Pixel"`. You can adjust Cache Length due to your datasets. But remember to use profiler (ALT + F2 IN VS2022)

Comment: Hello Daniel, I once incorporated your suggestions into my program, but in fact it has become rather slower. Maybe it's because I'm showing some rows in color. The colors are lost after your changes as soon as I scroll. But thanks anyway for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `ScrollVIewer.CanContentScroll` to `true` maybe this works for you

Answer (score 0):

This is a performance issue in WPF that I reported a long time ago.

See

- [Issue #4768: Very low Text Rendering Performance due native C++ interop](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4768)
- [Issue #5305: [Performance] Rewrite DirectWriteForwarder in C# to improve rendering performance](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5305)

Unfortunately, the WPF team is not very active at the moment due to a lack of staff.

I could imagine that with .NET 7 we will get a little boost here through ([PGO - Profile Guided Optimizations](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64659)).

Comment: I am excited. Let's hope it gets better :)